# cannot create a file through fs.open() command, even though the file does not exists before

Tags: node.js

Its showing that file does not exist.But i have opened the file in wx mode(that means it should create file if it doesn't exist).Then why it is showing this error of file does not exist [check out this for code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HAV9.png)

Comment: Can you copy that code and post it here as part of your question instead of making it an image on a different site, so that in the future people can get the entire context. Remember to format the code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is the directory. You are trying to create a file in a directory path that does not exist. You van combine it with fs.mkdir https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback.

Something like this.

Create directory if it does not exists.

```
function ensureDirectory(path, mask) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.mkdir(path, mask, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code == 'EEXIST') return resolve(null);
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(null);
        });
    });
}
```

Open the file. At this point the path and file should exist.

```
function openFile(path, mask) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.open(path, mask, (err, file) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
            return resolve(file);
        });
    });
}
```

Test function

```
async function test() {
    const path = '/some/path';
    const mask = 'wx';
    try {
        await ensureDirectory(path, mask);
        await openFile(path, mask)
    } catch (err) {

    }
}
```

Have a look at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html for more information.